# SQL autocounter depending on a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery-sql

I am trying to create something like a sequence number that is iterating on each row by one and resetting when column shopID changes. But I would like to use a variable.

```
select 
   @Counter --what to do here?
   ,@data as Data
   ,case 
        when (ShopID.N.value('.', 'decimal(5,0)') = -1) then NULL 
        else ShopID.N.value('.', 'decimal(5,0)')
   end as ShopID 
 from @xmlRes.nodes('/Root/ResponseData/response/shopItems') as S(N)
    outer apply S.N.nodes('recordNumber') as ShopID(N)
```

I need to get something like this:

```
Counter |   Data    |  ShopID
--------------------------------------
   1    |   Sample  |     1
   2    |   Sample  |     1
   3    |   Sample  |     1
   1    |   Sample  |     2
   2    |   Sample  |     2
   3    |   Sample  |     2
   4    |   Sample  |     2
   1    |   Sample  |     3
```

Comment: why you want use variable instead just `row_number() over`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ShopID ORDER BY Data) as Counter,
   ,@data as Data
   ,case 
        when (ShopID.N.value('.', 'decimal(5,0)') = -1) then NULL 
        else ShopID.N.value('.', 'decimal(5,0)')
   end as ShopID 
 from @xmlRes.nodes('/Root/ResponseData/response/shopItems') as S(N)
    outer apply S.N.nodes('recordNumber') as ShopID(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
row_number() over (partition by ShopID)
```

You should also add an order by clause after partition by if you want your sequence numbers assigned in particular order.

Comment: `ORDER BY` isnt optional for `ROW_NUMBER()`  Check [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx): The ORDER BY clause determines the sequence in which the rows are assigned their unique ROW_NUMBER within a specified partition. It is required.